# Zip asynchronous and synchronous observables

Tags: java, rxjs, observable, rx-java

I have a synchronous observable and 10 other asynchronous observables which are dependent on the sync observable. how to zip these together and get the final result ? Zip accepts only 9 arguments.. if I have to split it into 2 zips, how to do it as I have only 1 synchronous observable. Please help.

Below is the code: Here account is synchronous..

Observable aObservable = getAObservable(accountId);
        Account account = aObservable.toBlocking().single();

```
    Observable<List<C>> cObservable = getCObservable(saleInfo);
    Observable<B> bObservable = getBObservable(account);
    Observable<D> dObservable = getDObservable(account);
    Observable<E> eObservable = getEObservable(account);
    Observable<F> fObservable = getFObservable(account);
    Observable<G> gObservable = getGObservable(account);
    Observable<H> hObservable = getHObservable(account);
    Observable<I> iObservable = getIObservable(account);
    Observable<J> jObservable = getJObservable(account);

    Observable<SaleFile> observable =
            Observable.zip(
                    cObservable,
                    bObservable,
                    dObservable,
                    eObservable,
                    fObservable,
                    gObservable,
                    hObservable,
                    iObservable,
                    jObservable,
                    (o1, o2, o3, o4, o5, o6, o7, o8, o9) ->
                            new SaleFile()
                                    .withA(account)
                                    .withB(o1)
                                    .withC(o2)
                                    .withD(o3)
                                    .withE(o4)
                                    .withF(o5)
                                    .withG(o6)
                                    .withH(o7)
                                    .withI(o8)
                                    .withJ(o9));

    return observable.toBlocking().single();
```

Comment: Can you please post your so-called synchronous observable code [though there nothing called "synchronous" observable - I think you mean that observable which immediately [no async call i.e. backend] completes or emit the values] as well as few async observables? Once we have a little bit of code then we will be able to provide a better solution.

Comment: I don't think there is anything as **synchronous observable**. Please add more code to show what you mean exactly.

Comment: I think zip accepts more than 9

Comment: Synchronous observables definitely do exist. Operators like `of(1)` create an observable that emits immediately, without pushing on call stack/event stack.

Comment: Updated question with the code..